# Оптимальный размер сайта

Tags: веб-программирование

Как вы считаете, какой размер страницы в КБ веб-сайта будет оптимален для мобильных платформ?

Comment: А в каких попугаях мерять размер сайта ?

Comment: Я имел введу размер страницы сайта (сейчас исправлю). Вот хотел бы услышать мнения остальных участников ХэшКода. Я, например, считаю оптимальным размер не более 150 Кб.

Comment: Средняя температура по больницам составляет 17.5 градуса по цельсию (с)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хм не более 150КБ
я в общем о сайтах напишу, не о wap

1. А если у тебя будет 2-5 баннеров на сайте, как тогда? (по 15-100КБ)
2. Картинки, фотки в кол-ве от 10 до 30 штук, это если фото сайт допустим (по N Кб)
3. Подгружаемые картинки
4. Скрипты
5. CSS

Считаю тут упор не на размер сайта нужно делать, а на оптимизацию отдачи контента пользователю. Мне вот если чесно, без разницы как откроется мой блог в деревне "НОВОПУПИНСК", 1Кб/сек пусть сидят и ждут. Я уверен что не буду оптимизировать под них.

В большинстве случаем инет сейчас с широким каналом предоставляется, так что либо пользователи со 128Кб сидят и ждут, другие платят за инет на 100р больше и не ждут.

Собственно для web платформ тут тоже идет оптимизация своя, и нужно будет думать. Я вот честно не люблю wap.site.domen мне голая информация текстовая не нравится, всегда смотрю сайты целиком.

Интересно сделать минимально сделай, те кто смотрят только текстовые сайты ну не знаю, 21 век, читать тексты когда, даже, мобильный инет всем по карману.

> для мобильных платформ

Тут конкретика нужна. я на планшете смотрю все целиком. Если это wap версия сайта то и написать нужно что wap.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен!

Comment: :) ух как. я тоже согласен раз все согласны!

Answer (score 2):

Категория мобильных устройств очень широка. Это могут быть

- телефоны с wap-браузером,
- смартоны с мобильным браузером,
- нетбуки с полнофункциональным браузером.

И для каждой из этих категорий, существенно свои требования по трафику.

Если вы имели в виду смартфоны, то можно в качестве ориентира взять популярные сайты:

- pda.rian.ru - 140k,
- pda.rbc.ru - 40k,
- pda.finam.ru - 140k.